# Validating array insertion in Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have Table1 with attribute attribute1, which is an array of integer. My controller allows for one insertion at a time. So, in the controller:

```
def add_attribute1_item
  table1 = Table1.find(params[:id])
  table1.attribute1 << add_params[:attribute1_item]
  table1.save!
  render json: table1
rescue
  render_errors_for(table1)
end
```

I want to validate this attribute1_item value, ignoring the old values that have been stored in attribute1 array, e.g. if table1.attribute1 contains 99 and I call the controller add_attribute1_item to add 100, I only want to check whether 100 is valid or not, ignoring 99.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
     .
     .
     .
  validate :attribute1_item_is_valid, if: -> { attribute1.present? }
     .
     .
     .
  def attribute1_item_is_valid
    # validate the item by accessing attribute1
  end
```

I am unsure with this approach because when I access attribute1 in attribute1_item_is_valid, it is the whole array instead of the new item. Is this approach good enough by calling attribute1.last() or is there a more correct method?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to validate this in the model, validate the form entry.

Create a model for the form and use normal validations.

```
class SomeForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :id, :attribute1_item

  validate :id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
  validate :attribute1_item, presence: true
end

def add_attribute1_item
  form = SomeForm.new(params)
  if form.invalid?
    # render form.errors
    return
  end

  table1 = Table1.find(form.id)
  table1.attribute1 << form.attribute1_item
  table1.save!
  render json: table1
rescue
  render_errors_for(table1)
end
```

Comment: If you're using Rails 5.1+ use `attribute :id, :integer` and `attrribute :attribute1_item` instead of `attr_accessor`. The attributes api will create attributes that actually behave much like ActiveRecord attributes so that you can call `.attributes` on the model or serialize it.